# Apache Proxy Configuration for Request Methods

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I want to hide my HTTP webapi behind a Apache Proxy. My current configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:8180>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /tools/Apache24/conf/ssl/---.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /tools/Apache24/conf/ssl/---.key

ServerName some.server.some.where
DocumentRoot "/applications/------/dist"
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /api/(.*)           http://localhost:8182/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPass /api/ http://localhost:8182/  
ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://localhost:8182/   

<Directory /applications/------/dist>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

With this I can access my api via /api, but it only works for GET requests? What do I have to do to also allow POST, PUT and DELETE?
BR,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you have two directives that more or less should do the same, use either

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /api/(.*)           http://localhost:8182/$1 [P,L]
```

or

```
ProxyPass /api/ http://localhost:8182/  
ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://localhost:8182/
```

but not both at the same time. (My personal preference is the ProxyPass stanza).

Unless otherwise configured that should reverse proxy all methods and when GET works, POST and the others should also work. (Unless you of course forbid them elsewhere.)

But there is whole range of scenarios where using a URL path of `/api/` on the reverse proxy  but installing the actual API in the root `/` of `http://localhost:8182/` might fail in interesting ways.

Comment: Ok. I understand, however using only one of them also gives the same result ("Cannot PUT /somecall/somevalue/..."). I don't see any other rule preventing PUT/POST. Also if I do the same on a different port separate from the static files everything works fine. Any other ideas?

Comment: As any unintentional reader might have already expected, the problem was in my underlying API. Aaaargh, why have I taken this profession.